# activmemq.packages.trust-all does not trust all SSL certificates

Tags: spring-boot, ssl-certificate, activemq-classic

In my Spring Boot app part of my `application.yml` is as follows:

```
spring:
  activemq:
    broker-url: ssl://10.68.84.40:61617
    user: admin
    password: admin
    packages:
      trust-all: true
```

Where `10.68.84.40:61617` is an endpoint added to `activemq.xml`:

```xml
<transportConnector name="ssl"      uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

Spring Boot official document is way too brief about usage of ActiveMQ. I dig into `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.activemq.ActiveMQProperties` source code and see that setting `spring.activemq.packages.trust-all` to true should trust all server certs, but it still gets `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`.

Then I see another property `spring.activemq.packages.trusted` , but I wonder what should be put there.

Added: using openssl, sees CN of the server cert is just `localhost`. The application is calling using an IP.

Answer (score 0):

The setting `spring.activemq.packages.trust-all` has *nothing* to do with SSL certificates and [Spring's source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.7.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/activemq/ActiveMQProperties.java) gives no indication that it does. It's related to the deserialization of JMS `ObjectMessage` instances. See more in the [ActiveMQ Classic documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage).

Unfortunately there is no way to force the OpenWire JMS client from ActiveMQ Classic to "trust all" SSL certificates. However, you could get this behavior from the Core JMS client from ActiveMQ Artemis if you decided to migrate. See details [here](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/configuring-transports.html#configuring-netty-ssl).

Comment: Justin, it looks like you might need to mention the specific version of the ActiveMQ client. I tested it with the 5.16 client, but it's giving an "invalid parameter" error. Also, I couldn't find that parameter in the official documentation. Do you have a reference or more info on it?

Comment: Upon a closer look at the source code I've revised my answer. Previously I had found [NettyTransportSslOptions](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/main/activemq-amqp/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/amqp/client/transport/NettyTransportSslOptions.java#L224), but I see now that it is only used by an AMQP _test_ client, not the OpenWire JMS client. Also, it's worth noting that the ActiveMQ Classic documentation is quite out of date in a lot of places so it's not uncommon to find supported parameters that aren't actually documented.